# Unfair treatment by the community?

Tags: support, status-completed

Why are some questions "too localized" while some aren't?

First question,

> [Programmer's salary in UK](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/19/5940)

Second question,

> [Computer jobs in Singapore?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/22818/5940)

One gets closed and the other doesn't. Both are country specific questions. Do people from different countries deserve different treatment?

Comment: I voted to close the first one. You're welcome.

Comment: Why the down vote to this question? I mean, really!

Comment: This is a good point. I have repeatedly seen US/UK related questions staying open, and identical counterparts referring to other countries get closed as "too localized" on SO. That is perfectly understandable because the audience mostly is from the US and the UK and bound to feel that way, but it's far from fair

Comment: I voted to close the first one as well.  Sometimes we just miss questions.

Comment: @Jungle - down votes on metas often mean "I disagree" rather than indicating the question isn't useful. Don't take it personally and as there's no separate rep here it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Third vote to close on first one

Comment: they're both closed now. the system works!

Comment: Some questions slips :-) Now it's ok.

Comment: Thanks for all the response. Both are closed now (although I imagined the other way around - both open). But now it seems fair.

Comment: But shouldn't we want to be able to post questions that are, for example, UK-specific? After all there are loads of questions tagged GIT, but there are, I suggest, many more UK-programmers than there are GIT users.

Comment: @WinstonChurchill: I would agree.

Comment: @WinstonChurchill Joel actually talks to this directly in [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4818/what-questions-should-be-closed-with-reason-too-localized/87415#87415) and makes the identical point but with Montreal and oCaml. I think in the cases described above where problematic because of the time factor, since the answer becomes less and less useful as time goes on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When questions are moderated, generally people use their best judgement to determine the merits of the question *by itself*. Does it meet our site's standards? Does the question make sense? Is it answerable? I don't want to say it's completely non-existant, but it's exceedingly rare that community moderation takes into account the country of origin for a question.

That is, community moderation is governed by humans who occasionally make mistakes or overlook certain things. One question might get the benefit of community moderation, while another slips through the cracks.

In the cases where a question slips through the cracks and you notice it, it's important to do something about it:

- Edit the question to bring it in line with our site's [standards](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq)
- Comment on the question to provide feedback as to why the question doesn't fit
- Use voting to down-vote bad things, up-vote good things, and close off-topic things.
- If it's something that really needs attention right away, flag it for moderator review.